# Error al ingresar la credencial de autentificación de twitter en firebase

Tags: firebase, login, flutter, autenticación, twitter

La configuración de **Firebase** esta todo bien ya que lo probé con la autentificación de **Facebook**

## Mi error es el siguiente

```
W/BiChannelGoogleApi(19196): [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod() returned Gms: com.google.firebase.auth.api.internal.zzak@b78aced
I/flutter (19196): PlatformException(ERROR_INVALID_CREDENTIAL, The supplied auth credential is malformed or has expired. [ Failed to fetch resource from https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true, http status: 401, http response: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]} ], null)
E/GraphResponse(19196): {HttpStatus: 403, errorCode: 4, subErrorCode: -1, errorType: OAuthException, errorMessage: (#4) Application request limit reached}
```

### Mi código es el siguiente

```
final TwitterLoginResult result = await _twitterLogin.authorize();
switch (result.status) {
  case TwitterLoginStatus.loggedIn:
    var session = result.session;
    print("Si entro  userName= ${session.username}, UserId = {${session.userId}}");
    print("--->>>sessionToken = {${session.token}}, >>>sessionSecret={${session.secret}}");
    final AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
        authToken: session.token, authTokenSecret: session.secret);
        return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).uid;
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.cancelledByUser:
    print("El usuario Cancelo---------");
    break;
  case TwitterLoginStatus.error:
    print("---------Salio un error");
    break;
}
```

Parece que el error es al ingresarlo en **Firebase**.

```
final AuthCredential credential = TwitterAuthProvider.getCredential(
    authToken: session.token, authTokenSecret: session.secret);
    return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).uid;
```

El código de **Facebook** es el siguiente y no causa ningun error.

```
final result = await _facebookLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"]);
final AuthCredential credential = FacebookAuthProvider.getCredential(
  accessToken: result.accessToken.token,
);
return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).uid;
```